# OCaml from list [a1,...,ai,ai+1,....,an] to list [ai+1,...,an,a1,....ai]

Tags: list, pattern-matching, ocaml

I have a problem with this exercise!

My idea is to create two functions:

1. The first function creates the list `[ai + 1, ..., an]`
2. The second function, taking as input the result of the first function and returns the result: `[ai + 1, ..., an, a1, ..., ai]`

The problem is that I just started programming with Ocaml and I don't understand very well how to use it. So i have some errors that I don't know how to solve.
My code is this:

```
let rec produceprima l i =
 let rec produceprima_aux l i acc=
  let rec aux l i acc l1 =
   match l with
    []-> []
    |x::y -> if(acc>i) then aux y i acc+1 l1@[x] 
             else aux y i acc+1 l1
  in aux l i acc l1
 in produceprima_aux l i acc;;

let rec produceseconda l i =
 let rec produceseconda_aux l i acc=
  let rec aux l i acc l1 =
   match l with
    []-> []
    |x::y -> if(acc<=i) then aux y i acc+1 l1@[x] 
  in aux l i acc l1
 in produceseconda_aux l i acc;;
```

The error of first function is:

```
Error: This expression has type 'a -> 'b list
       but an expression was expected of type int
```

The second function i have to try but for sure it have error!

Answer (score 0):

Expression `f x+1` is parsed by the compiler as `(f x) + 1`. The fact, that you omitted white spaces around the operator name didn't give it any precedence. So, you should write `aux y i (acc+1) l1`, instead of `aux y i acc+1 l1`.

This is a very common mistake. I would suggest you to try [OCamlPro](https://try.ocamlpro.com/) tutorial. Especially, Lesson 5, that focuses on syntax traps.

Comment: Thank you so much :D i try it! For sure i will see the tutorial!